# "with" keyword changes the results

Tags: neo4j, cypher

query 1

```
MATCH (n:PC)-[r:C1|C2|U]->(n2) WHERE r.date IS NULL OR (r.date > 1 AND r.date < 15)
WITH n,n2, 
reduce(t = 0, r in [x IN collect(r) WHERE type(x) = 'C1' or type(x) = 'C2'] | t + r.amount) as totalAmount1, 
reduce(t = 0, r in [x IN collect(r) WHERE type(x) = 'U' ] | t + r.amount) as totalAmount2 
WHERE totalAmount1 >= 1291 AND totalAmount2 >= 1000
RETURN COUNT(*)
```

query 2

```
MATCH (n:PC)-[r:C1|C2|U]->(n2) WHERE r.date IS NULL OR (r.date > 1 AND r.date < 15)
WITH n, 
reduce(t = 0, r in [x IN collect(r) WHERE type(x) = 'C1' or type(x) = 'C2'] | t + r.amount) as totalAmount1, 
reduce(t = 0, r in [x IN collect(r) WHERE type(x) = 'U' ] | t + r.amount) as totalAmount2 
WHERE totalAmount1 >= 1291 AND totalAmount2 >= 1000
RETURN COUNT(*)
```

As you can see, these 2 queries are VERY similar to each other. **The only difference is I used `WITH n,n2` instead of `WITH n` in the second query.** I expect both of them to return THE SAME results.

**BUT** query 1 returns 0 the other returns 113. why? how?

Note: the database contains nearly 7 million nodes and 10 million edges.

Comment: Actually you are grouping the result of the first part(MATCH before the WITH) on one key in the first query and on two keys in the second query. These queries are way much different.

Comment: To see the actual result return all the columns available you will understand the difference

Comment: In the docs it says "The WITH clause allows query parts to be chained together, piping the results from one to be used as starting points or criteria in the next." I don't understand how "grouping" happens. Even if it happens, shouldn't group with n,n2 give a lot more results?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation on how [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) like `COLLECT` work, especially the information on "grouping keys".

All `WITH` or `RETURN` clause terms that do NOT use aggregating functions are used as "grouping keys", which control what data should be aggregated together.

Query 1 has 2 grouping keys (`n` and `n2`), but Query 2 only has 1 (`n`). So, you would generally expect the resulting aggregations to be different.

Comment: I think I should use java or there should be a language like python. These kind of database query languages are not transparent enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query 1 reduces for each n only the paths that lead to a specific n2

Your Query 2 reduces for each n all paths that lead to any node

Hence, the number of paths, and thus of items in the collect(r) of Query 2 is greater than for Query 1

Assuming that the amounts are  > 0, Query 2 has a higher count of results for which the WHERE clause returns true.

In fact, it's not the WITH keyword that changes the results, but it's the list of variables / placeholders that you provide.